# JavaScript - querySelectorAll and lower/uppercase

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with `querySelectorAll`. I use it like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, (btn) => {
  this.setItemActive(target);
});

setItemActive(item) {
  _.addClass(document.querySelectorAll(`[title="${item}"]`)[0], this.activeClass);
}
```

And it works, if provided `item` is written exactly the same as the `target` value in the said element. But I use `text-transform` on my buttons and it is causing a problem. I tried adding `toLowerCase()` to both, but this didn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me - title is not very comfortable to use in such situations. Think about a kind of identificator.

---

Proposition:

in your HTML code, make additional attr, kind of :

```
<a title="WrIght As You Wish" data-title="strictlowercasetitle" >Your info with title</a>
```

and in your JS :

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, (btn) => {
  this.setItemActive(target);
});

setItemActive(item) {
  // make item lower case
  _.addClass(document.querySelectorAll(`[data-title="${item.toLowerCase()}"]`)[0], this.activeClass);
}
```

Comment: Well, your answer inspired me to write a method that adds `id` that is a slug of the title. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to `setItemActive` function and wrote this below function. 
Hope this will be helpful to you

```
function _setItem(item){
    console.log(item)
    var m = document.querySelectorAll('a[title='+item+']')[0];
    console.log(m)
    }
    _setItem("WrIght");
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vfrm84kv/)